# enable the graph inside the navigator in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am working on highcharts.Inside some charts the graph which is displayed inside the navigator which shows the level variation of the data is disabled.In some charts it is showing and in some charts its not.How to enable that?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `navigator.enabled = true`, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.enabled).

Comment: That i have done.The navigator is there.It is visible but the graph inside the navigator which displays the variation levels is not coming.

Comment: What errors do you have in console? Which version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the reason was that my data was not sorted.

"Highcharts Error #15

Highcharts expects data to be sorted

This happens when you are trying to create a line series or a stock chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X order. For performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it is required that the implementer pre-sorts the data."